# Qt Open file with context menu entry/shell extensions [Windows]

Tags: c++, windows, qt, contextmenu

I'm looking to have a way of opening files in my Qt app within a context menu, like opening any image file in Photos or Photoshop. Mostly what I'm finding though is either possibly out of date ways of doing it, like way earlier versions of Qt, or incomplete posts about doing something with shell extensions, but it's mostly adding an icon to custom file extensions in explorer, not the opening actions. Or ways of doing it with the general Windows API I think, which I don't know how this would "connect" with my Qt app to open a file in it, and the windows api is very scary to me.

Is the way of doing now with a newly added module in Qt using C++, or maybe something with an "installscript.qs" file, or "package.xml"? I've never seen or used a .qs file before. Basically, I'm not sure where to look for how to do it the most updated and easiest way.

The screenshot below is an example of the functionality im talking about. With my Qt app not being open, a file of the types I want (.jpg, .png, .gif, etc) is right clicked, and I can click like "Edit with MyQtAppName", or open the "Open with" sub menu and click "MyQtAppName". Then ultimately this files full path would be passed into my Qt app as a string somehow. I don't know how this pass of the path string happens yet, but yeah. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Issue is not Qt related. This menus are provided by system. To add your own entry you have to change some system setting during installation process to let Windows know that your application provides functionality for `*.jpg` files.

Comment: @MarekR Okay, that's the feeling I was getting looking into this stuff. I was just kinda hoping Qt had a built in way of handling this for ease of use or whatever, since the way it seems you do it is kind of complicated. Thank you.

Comment: I was wrong Qt has some support for it: https://wiki.qt.io/Assigning_a_file_type_to_an_Application_on_Windows